# grep takes forever to execute on Ubuntu for Windows

Tags: grep, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed Ubuntu on WSL. What ever grep command I fire takes forever to execute and not return anything. Even if I am in a small folder and I grep something obvious it does not return.
Any info would be helpful.
Thank you.

*Edit. I am out of ubuntu folder. It has a mount folder for C and then I have moved to a windows directory that contains the files that I am interested in.

Comment: Needs more details - command being run, output of `which grep`, WSL version. Edit your question and include this.

Comment: Are you sure you provide the last file argument (name or glob expression)?  `grep "pattern" filename`. Just in case, because if you don't, then grep seems to "take forever".

Comment: Windows text files may have unusual locale character encodings. In particular, they use CRLF line terminations, so matches at the ends of lines in Linux tend to not match the invisible `\r`. I would have expected WSL to deal with automatically, but ...

Comment: Please state the exact command(s) you think are running slower than expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found out. @thanasisp your comment has helped me a lot. I was firing

```
grep "pattern"
```

and expected to search all files under my current directory. I should have declared that I wanted all files to be searched

```
grep "pattern" *
```

Comment: Note that `grep "pattern" *` will i) try to `grep` in any subdirectores (not the files in the subdirs, the subdirs themselves) so expect some errors and ii) will not grep any files in subdirectories. If you want recursive `grep` that is to grep in all files in any subdirectory as well, use `grep "pattern" -R .`